# MySQL Update Sort Order Column Using Counter

Tags: mysql

I have a table which has rows inserted and removed which creates problems with the Sort Order. Sometimes I'm finding duplicate SortOrder values such as:

1
2
2
3
4
4

I reset the SortOrder values - I just can't seem to figure out the right query.

e.g.

Table1 contains columns: ssID, showID, sName, sDisplay, SortOrder

Primary Key is ssID

When new data gets inserted/removed I need to reset the SortOrder

New data is being inserted using a number of different procedures hence there's a need to clean the table up.

I can get the SortOrder values I want with this:

```
SET @t1=0;
SELECT *, 
    @t1 := @t1+1 As counter 
FROM Table1  
WHERE showID = 123 
ORDER BY SortOrder ASC
```

From this, 'counter' is populated with 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 etc but I can't work out how to UPDATE the results from the SELECT to replace SortOrder with each new value from counter

Comment: update your question and add  info for the primary key of the table  Table1 .. and add  the sql update code you are trying ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the table1 prumary key is the column  `your_table1_primary_key`

You coudl try  using

```
SET @t1=0;

UPDATE Table1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT your_table1_primary_key, @t1 := @t1+1 As counter 
    FROM Table1 
    WHERE showID = 123 
    ORDER BY SortOrder ASC
) t on t.your_table1_primary_key = Table1.your_table1_primary_key
SET Table1.SortOrder =  t.counter
```